# Visual Studio 2005 Team Foundation Server not working after IP changes

Tags: visual-studio-2005, tfs

Visual Studio 2005 SP1

My team has change the IP to the TFS servers. For some team projects I never check out before, I can't download it after the IP changed. I got an error message 'Error: the item $/ already exists' when double clicking on Source Control entry in Team Explorer. I looked up online and find some threads saying deleting below 2 folders will work, but it didn't.

> c:\documents and settings\me\local settings\application data\microsoft\team foundation\1.0
>
> c:\Documents and Settings\me\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\Team Explorer

Has anyone got this problem before? Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A couple suggestions:

1. Try re-mapping your workspaces.
2. Delete the cache on the server as well.  Instructions are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716691%28VS.90%29.aspx) for TFS 2008-- I'm not sure what version of TFS you are using.